# Passing multiple parameters as a single macro argumment

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, template-meta-programming

### The question

The C preprocessor has the `#`, which converts into a raw string any expression written after it. For example:

```
#define make_string(x) #x

int a , b;
const char my_string[] = make_string( a + b ); //my_string holds "a + b"
```

**Is there any way to perform the inverse process?**
I mean, getting a raw string and convert it into a secuence of tokens. For example (`~#` is the theorical preprocessor operator which does it):

```
#define make_tokens(x) ~#x

int a = 0 , b = 1;
int c = make_tokens( "a + b" ); //c holds 1 (The result of a + b addition)
```

### Some context (Or "*I'm falling on the XY problem?*")

I'm writting a template metaprogramming library which is heavily based on definning metafunctions and specializing them to get different behaviour (Like function overloading).
For example:

```
//Metafunction declaration:
template<typename T , typename U>
struct better_type;


//Metafunction specialization (overload)
template<>
struct better_type<char,unsigned char>
{
    using result = char;
};
```

The library assumes that a metafunction is any template with a `result` public alias. So the user has to do the common `typename function</*function argumments*/>::result` to get the result of the function.

To avoid that, I take advantage of C++11 template aliases and just define functions in two parts:

- **Function implementation**: A metafunction of the above form which implements the functionality.

  ```
  template<typename T>
  struct function_impl;
  ```

  To implement (overload) his own version of the function, the user specializes this template:

  ```
  template<>
  struct function_impl<bool>
  {
      using result = /* something */;
  };
  ```
- **Function declaration**: This defines the function interface for the user. Its just an alias of the real metafunction.

  ```
  template<typename T>
  using function = typename function_impl<T>::result;
  ```

So function declarations are always a pair of declarations: The function implementation and the user interface alias.

Now my goal is to automatice that declarations in some generic whay, using the CPP. Something like:

```
#define define_function( template_args , function_name , function_args ) \
        template< template_args >                                        \
        struct function_name##_impl;                                     \
                                                                         \
        template< template_args >                                        \
        using function_name = typename function_name##_impl< function_args >::type
```

That could be used as:

```
define_function( typename T , my_function , T );
```

And produces the following code without any problem:

```
template< typename T >
struct mi_function_impl;

template< typename T >
using mi_function = typename my_function_impl< T >::type;
```

But consider other usage example:

```
define_function( typename T , typename U , mi_binary_function , T , U );
```

Of course `typename T , typename U` are intended to be the first macro argumment, and `T , U` the second one. But this cannot work because they are viewed as five different macro argumments.
Thats why I was thinking about token generation, because with that feature the macro could be rewitten as:

```
#define define_function( template_args , function_name , function_args ) \
        template< make_tokens(template_args) >                           \
        struct function_name##_impl;                                     \
                                                                         \
        template< template_args >                                        \
        using function_name = typename function_name##_impl< make_tokens(function_args) >::type
```

and multiple parameters would be passed as an unique raw string generating the expected result:

```
define_function( "typename T , typename U" , mi_binary_function , "T , U" );
```

Comment: Have you tried (I haven't so I'm not writing an answer of of it): 
`define_function( (typename T, typename U), mi_binary_function, (T, U)`? That may be a little easier to deal with.

Comment: @MatsPetersson that doesn't work, because the preprocessor only takes the argumment and puts it inside the `< >`, so you get the invalid syntax `template<(typename T , typename U)>`

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of then having a second macro that gets rid of the extra parenthesis. I'm 100% certain there is no way to remove double-quotes from macro arguments.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Isn't it something like `#define strip(...) __VA_ARGS__`, used via `#define define_function(A, B, C) template< strip A > struct B ## _impl;`? [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1429bffb19132f8b)

Comment: For completeness, there is exactly one case where string literals *do* get decomposed, and that is with `_Pragma`. But that wouldn't help you here.

Comment: Yep, if the problem is just how to pack many things into one macro argument, I believe that's been solved. You may like to check out Boost.Preprocessor for an example of taking something simple to the extreme if you like some inspiration.

Comment: There's also still the (admittedly ugly) option of `define_function(typename T COMMA typename U, ...)`. This is a single macro argument, even if `COMMA` is a macro expanding to `,`.

Comment: Regarding XY: Maybe it *would* have been better to ask "Can I pass several packs of arguments through preprocessor macros?" :-)

Comment: Btw if your metafunctions only accept types (not non-type arguments), you might be able to just specify the *number* of parameters, and let the names be created automagically.

Comment: @dyp no, they are not type parameters only. In that case there would be any problem, because I could use one typelist only, for example.

Comment: @KerrekSB I could rephrase the question, but I'm curious (besides the main problem) about the de-stringzing feature. Of course if thats not possible, I should rewrite the question to only cover the macro argumments problem.

Comment: @dyp your `strip` macro is my solution, I think. I will accept it if you write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to the X/Y problem is to use parentheses instead of quotation marks:

```
define_function( (typename T, typename U) , mi_binary_function , (T, U) );
// yields:
template< typename T, typename U > struct mi_binary_function_impl; template< typename T, typename U > using mi_binary_function = typename mi_binary_function_impl < T, U >::type;
```

can be implemented as:

```
#define strip_parens(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define define_function( template_args , function_name , function_args ) \
    template< strip_parens template_args >                               \
    struct function_name##_impl;                                         \
                                                                         \
    template< strip_parens template_args >                               \
    using function_name = typename function_name##_impl                  \
                                   < strip_parens function_args >::type  // end
```

---

But we can also generate the parameter names automatically (you give them new names in specializations anyway):

```
define_function(foo, (class, int, typename));
// yields:
template< class T0, int T1, typename T2 > struct foo_impl; template< class T0, int T1, typename T2 > using foo = typename foo_impl < T0, T1, T2 > :: result;
```

can be implemented as:

```
#define gen_single_param_name(number_plus_2)                    \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(T, BOOST_PP_DEC(BOOST_PP_DEC(number_plus_2)))  // end

#define gen_single_param(s, data, elem) elem gen_single_param_name(s)
#define gen_params_from_seq(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(gen_single_param, _, seq)

#define gen_single_arg(s, data, elem) gen_single_param_name(s)
#define gen_args_from_seq(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(gen_single_arg, _, seq)

#define define_function_impl(name, param_seq, arg_seq)                    \
    template< BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(param_seq) >                              \
    struct name ## _impl;                                                 \
                                                                          \
    template< BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(param_seq) >                              \
    using name = typename name ## _impl                                   \
                 < BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(arg_seq) > :: result                 // end

#define define_function_seq(name, param_seq)                    \
    define_function_impl(name, gen_params_from_seq(param_seq),  \
                         gen_args_from_seq(param_seq))          // end

#define define_function(name, param_list) \
    define_function_seq(name, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ param_list)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how stable that `s` argument is. You might need to work around it a bit, but OTOH the only guarantee we need here is that it can be used to create unique identifier for each element in the sequence. The `BOOST_PP_DEC` is not required, actually.

Comment: Btw. with version of boost and the version of clang++ at coliru, `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ` seems to be broken. I've had that issue before..

Comment: The boost solution looks great. Thanks. I was just wondering if there is a simpler way to generate the template arguments. I don't want to depend in any external dependencies, Boost included. btw I could check the boost::preprocessor implementation and get what I need. But thats like reinventing the wheel I think.